# kafka mongo-db connector KCQL support configuration-- Distributed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are configuring our kafka sink connector with datamountaineer class to get upsert functionality(insert/update) but we are facing below error

--Error

```
**NoSuchMethodFound **
```

--Configurations

```
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.mongodb.sink.MongoSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=orders-topic
connect.mongo.kcql=INSERT INTO orders SELECT * FROM orders-topic
connect.mongo.db=connect
connect.mongo.connection=mongodb://localhost:27017
connect.mongo.batch.size=10
```

[image: Error log]

Comment: Can you be a bit more descriptive please? How are you running Kafka Connect? How have you installed it? from where?

Comment: Could you please tell us exact issue?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Two clusters. we are in distributed mode . it's unmanaged kafka cluster but we are using class file datamountanineer to get upsert functionality to sink connector for mongodb. and i updated my question with error picture attached

Comment: tried it in both mode (Standalone , Distributed mode ) but same error occurred .

Comment: @RobinMoffatt ...

Comment: @cricket_007 may be he can help

Comment: You're probably better speaking to Data Mountaineer since it's their connector.

Comment: could you please get us to the point where we can use ```upsert (insert / update 
)```  functionality within mongo kafka sink connector ? @RobinMoffatt

Comment: I'm not familiar with this connector. It's not that I'm refusing to help - I just don't know the answer. You could always try a different sink connector : https://www.confluent.io/hub/mongodb/kafka-connect-mongodb

Comment: anyway thanks for your time @RobinMoffatt